# Binding the dependency of a Laravel Service Provider inside the provider itself?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am just starting to get the hang of Service Providers and the IoC container, however one thing is confusing me. I have a SpamServiceProvider that requires two other classes to function. However one of those classes, InvalidKeywords, has a array $blacklist parameter which needs to be passed to its constructor.

If I register that class in the AppServiceProvider and pass in the $blacklist array, everything works fine. However, if I try to bind the class in the SpamServiceProvider instead it will not inject the $blacklist into InvalidKeywords constructor.

So I guess my question is why is this? And is there a way to keep bindings like this together in a single container or do I simply have to bind InvalidKeywords inside the AppServiceProvider?

This works

```
class SpamServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

/**
 * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $defer = true;

/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind(SpamManager::class, function ($app) {
        return new SpamManager(new InvalidKeywords, new RepeatedCharacters);
    });
}

}


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(InvalidKeywords::class, function ($app) {
        return new InvalidKeywords(config('spam.blacklist'));
    });
}
}
```

This does not work

```
class SpamServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

/**
 * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $defer = true;

/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind(InvalidKeywords::class, function ($app) {
        return new InvalidKeywords(config('spam.blacklist'));
    });

    $this->app->bind(SpamManager::class, function ($app) {
        return new SpamManager(new InvalidKeywords, new RepeatedCharacters);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case you're not resolving the `InvalidKeywords` class from the container, simply creating a new instance. Instead, try using `app` or `resolve` helpers when creating the `SpamManager`:

```
$this->app->bind(SpamManager::class, function ($app) {
    return new SpamManager(resolve(InvalidKeywords::class), resolve(RepeatedCharacters::class));
});

// or 
$this->app->bind(SpamManager::class, function ($app) {
    return new SpamManager(app(InvalidKeywords::class), app(RepeatedCharacters::class));
});
```

I would create a singleton with `InvalidKeywords` as well:

```
$this->app->singleton(InvalidKeywords::class, function ($app) {
    return new InvalidKeywords(config('spam.blacklist'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this!!! I used $app->make() and it all started working :)